# Doctrine2 ODM Free Memory

Tags: mongodb, memory, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to browse 15 000 documents in MongoDB.
The php usage memory explodes whith Doctrine ODM. 
I make a sequential script but the memory still grows.

```
$nbrNoticesTotal = $noticesNbr['count'];
        $page = 0;
        $limit = 500;
        $pt = 0;
        $ptTotal = 0;
        $notices = $dm->getRepository('Notice')->findLimit($page, $limit)->toArray();
        if ($nbrNoticesTotal > 0) {
            while ($ptTotal < $nbrNoticesTotal) {
                if ($pt >= $limit) {
                    unset($notices);
                    $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');
                    $page += $limit;
                    $notices = $dm->getRepository('Notice')->findLimit($page, $limit)->toArray();
                    $pt = 0;
                }
                foreach ($notices as $key => $notice) {

                    $pt++;
                    $ptTotal++;
                    //unset($notice);
                    unset($notices[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Exemple to memory_get_usage() :

```
2012-06-28 14:53:08.541-defaultLogger-DEBUG Start : 20,339,624
2012-06-28 14:53:10.154-defaultLogger-DEBUG get package : 1 - 64,207,344
2012-06-28 14:53:10.891-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 64,250,536
2012-06-28 14:53:11.642-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 64,246,952
2012-06-28 14:53:12.375-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 64,243,368
2012-06-28 14:53:13.140-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 64,239,784
2012-06-28 14:53:13.911-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 64,236,264
2012-06-28 14:53:15.359-defaultLogger-DEBUG get package : 2 - 104,447,576
2012-06-28 14:53:17.259-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 104,482,168
2012-06-28 14:53:19.013-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 104,478,584
2012-06-28 14:53:20.771-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 104,475,000
2012-06-28 14:53:22.650-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 104,471,416
2012-06-28 14:53:24.575-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 104,467,840
2012-06-28 14:53:26.081-defaultLogger-DEBUG get package : 3 - 139,016,152
2012-06-28 14:53:29.192-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 139,046,936
2012-06-28 14:53:32.560-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 139,043,360
2012-06-28 14:53:35.456-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 139,039,912
2012-06-28 14:53:38.229-defaultLogger-DEBUG pointer time : 139,036,336
```

What can i do to clear the memory? (unset doesn't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use **EntityManager::clear** method to tell DC to clear objects.

Also as far I remember foreach makes copy of the array and unset in foreach loop to unset element from array won't work - by that I mean the memory usage, try using **for** instead of **foreach**.

Also try using **$value = null;** Instead of unset becouse unset just tells PHP's GC that it can remove this from memory - but You don't know when he gonna do this. There are some topics about unset & null - I can be wrong at this point.

I hope this will help You.

Also there can be other place where memory grows.

Comment: Perfect.
I use DocumentManager::clear and $value=null;
thank's

Comment: If it helps, please edit the question and post the difference for other people :)